# Отсутствует перевод описания привилегии «просмотр голосов»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника, привилегии

Может и мелочь, но всё-таки. Отсутствует перевод.

> See vote breakout

[image: Краткое описание привелегии]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14132

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая  rev 2021.8.18.40012